# @lru_cache on function with commutative arguments

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-programming, commutativity

I am calculating the Hamming distance between 2 strings where `Hamming(A,B) == Hamming(B,A)`

The function signature is

```
@lru_cache
def Hamming(A:str,B:str)->int:
    ...
```

How can I modify @lru_cache or the function to ignore argument order when indexing into the cache?

Comment: You can't, you'd have to write your own caching implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert an extra function call that predictably rearranges the arguments:

```
def Hamming(A: str, B: str) -> int:
    if B < A:
        A, B = B, A
    return _Hamming(A, B) 

@lru_cache
def _Hamming(A, B):
    ...
```

Comment: I was just writing this answer. +1. Also, I'd personally not use `*sorted(..)` for 2 items. Maybe a simple if-else could be more readable?

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree, but the general point comes across. As you point out, this may be applied to more than 2 or even an unspecified number of `*args`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
from cachetools import cached
from cachetools.keys import hashkey

@cached(cache={}, key=lambda A, B: hashkey((A, B) if A < B else (B, A)))
def Hamming(A: str, B: str) -> int:
    ...
```

Or in general:

```
@cached(cache={}, key=lambda *args: hashkey(tuple(sorted(args))))
def Hamming(A: str, B: str) -> int:
    ...
```